# How do I add lyrics to a song in iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipod, lyrics

How do I add lyrics to a song in iTunes so that it shows the lyrics on the iPod/iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the song in iTunes and choose Get Info. Second from the right is the section "Lyrics" where you can paste the lyrics of the song. The lyrics will show up on top of the album art when the song is played on the iPod. Tap the album art to show it if you don't have all the controls visible.

Comment: I tried to copy-paste the lyrics into the lyrics tab on get info but when I disconnected my iPhone, the lyrics wouldn't show up while playing the song. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Nina Did the phone have time to sync before you disconnected it?

Comment: @Nina There's also a setting under Music for showing the Lyrics (& Podcast Info), make sure that is set to On.

Answer (score 6):

I own iClip Lyrics and I was fortunate enough to download it before they discontinued it.
(It still works even though they aren't developing it, and if you can find it online I highly recommend it)

All you had to do was play a song, it would search the internet, grab the lyrics, and automatically add them to the ID3 tag for the the MP3 file.

There are some other apps out there that do basically the same thing:

1. GimmieSomeTune
2. TuneLyrics
3. iLyrics

Comment: Alex, can I ask where iClip gets its lyrics from?  Are they in any way offical, or from a user-submitted site which often have misheard and incorrect lyrics?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, iClip was pulling it's lyrics from specific set of sites on the internet. And if I remember correctly, people did not like this...The developer's blog/website explains what happened. (if it's still up)

Answer (score 1):

I've written a post on my blog to showcase my findings regarding this question. Check it out:

[Software to add Lyrics to MP3 files ID3 metadata](http://www.leniel.net/2011/01/software-add-lyrics-mp3-files-metadata.html)

Answer (score 0):

you right click (control click on mac) on song and click get info. From there you press the lyrics tab and enter your lyrics. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To add lyrics to a song, I use this dashboard widget: [TunesTEXT](http://www.cyanworks.net/dboardTunesTEXT.html)
Very simple but very useful.